# Change database on the fly laravel 5

Tags: mysql, database, laravel-5

on the fly change database in laravel 5
Scenario is - User will register on a site. After registration it will create new database and tables for that user. Now when the new user will try to login, he should be able to connect with newly created database.

If 10 user register then it will create 10 database. Each user has own database.

Now how can I set database for user on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the config() helper function, i.e. calling it within a middleware or a controller.

Example: `config(['app.timezone' => 'America/Chicago']);`. Another approach, which might be even more suitable for you, is calling the "setConnection" method within the Eloquent "Model" class or setting its $connection variable (see https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L42)